# Restore or clone Windows 10 to another partition and dual-boot Windows 10 with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot, backup, system-restore, efi

I have two Windows 10 partitions on my disk and I could boot into both of them.
I could also backup one partition and restore it to the other, which was very convenient for updating and testing my system.
Unfortunately at some point restoring the system to another partition didn't work anymore and resulted in errors of `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT DEVICE` and similar problems.

I used *Paragon Backup and Revovery 14* and *AOMEI Backuper Standard 5.8.0*.

How can I restore the frist Windows 10 to the second partition and make it boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, after the restore process *Paragon Backup and Revovery 14* change the boot partition in a way that a Windows 1903 system cannot start. A `bcdboot e:\windows /v` fixes the problem. *AOMEI Backuper Standard 5.8.0* seems to have some other problem. I couldn't get it working. *Paragon Backup and Revovery 16* and *17* can backup a running Windows 10 and restore it to another partition.